# Composing function with higher arity in Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, function-composition, ramda.js

I'm eagerly trying to learn functional programming in js, but I am having a hard time. I feel like I am constantly doing stuff like this, which just doesn't feel right at all:

```
export const getParamFromUrl = R.curry((name, url) => R.compose(
    R.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${name}=([^&]*)`))
)(url));
```

I don't feel like I should be invoking compose immidiately. So what's the correct way to do function composition with an arity of say two?

EDIT: For clarity this is the actual function as it looks (and I know this it isn't the best way to get query strings)

```
/* util.toMaybe takes a function and a value and returns Nothing()
   if the function returns true and Just(value) if it returns false.
   I think this is the HM:
   util.toMaybe :: (a -> Boolean) -> a -> Maybe a
*/
export const getParamFromUrl = R.curry((name, url) => R.compose(
    R.chain(util.toMaybe(R.isEmpty)),
    R.map(R.nth(1)),
    util.toMaybe(R.isEmpty),
    R.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${name}=([^&]*)`))
)(url));
```

With the accepted answer this would the become:

```
export const getParamFromUrl = R.curry(R.compose(
    R.chain(util.toMaybe(R.isEmpty)),
    R.map(R.nth(1)),
    util.toMaybe(R.isEmpty),
    (name, url) => R.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${name}=([^&]*)`), url)
));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting the functional side of things. Do you need to curry right away? What's wrong with a regular function like `(name, url) => url.match(new RegExp())[1]` You can always wrap/curry that function later, right?

Comment: That's also a terribly unreliable way to parse URL parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean to do with that `compose` call.  The function will work equally well without it, and it's more clear.

```
const getParamFromUrl = R.curry((name, url) => 
    R.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${name}=([^&]*)`), url));
```

If you plan on adding another function into the composition then you can do it like this:

```
const getParamFromUrl = R.curry(R.compose(
    nth(1),
    (name, url) => R.match(new RegExp(`[?&]${name}=([^&]*)`), url)
));
```

Note that [for](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1260) [technical](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1318) [reasons](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1383), the result of `compose` is not auto-curried, so you need to do that yourself.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20getParamFromUrl_1%20%3D%20R.curry%28%28name%2C%20url%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%20%20%20%20R.match%28new%20RegExp%28%60[%3F%26]%24%7Bname%7D%3D%28[%5E%26]*%29%60%29%2C%20url%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getParamFromUrl_2%20%3D%20R.curry%28R.compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20nth%281%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%28name%2C%20url%29%20%3D%3E%20R.match%28new%20RegExp%28%60[%3F%26]%24%7Bname%7D%3D%28[%5E%26]*%29%60%29%2C%20url%29%0A%29%29%3B%0A%0A[%0A%20%20getParamFromUrl_1%28%27age%27%29%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fname%3Dfred%26age%3D17%27%29%2C%0A%20%20getParamFromUrl_2%28%27age%27%29%28%27http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fname%3Dfred%26age%3D17%27%29%2C%0A])**.

Comment: Thank you so much, composing the higher-arity function makes so much sense. I feel like this idea is exactly what I was looking for but just could not work out myself. I have edited my question to try and shed some light on why I used composition in the first place.